# Decimal Python vs. float runtime

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

Just a general question on what sort of runtime differences I should be expecting between using these two different data types.

My test:

```
test = [100.0897463, 1.099999939393,1.37382829829393,29.1937462874847272,2.095478262874647474]
test2 = [decimal.Decimal('100.0897463'), decimal.Decimal('1.09999993939'), decimal.Decimal('1.37382829829'), decimal.Decimal('29.1937462875'), decimal.Decimal('2.09547826287')]

def average(numbers, ddof=0):
    return sum(numbers) / (len(numbers)-ddof)

%timeit average(test)
%timeit average(test2)
```

The differences in runtime are:
1000000 loops, best of 3: 364 ns per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.3 µs per loop

So using decimal was about 200 times slower than using floats. Is this type of difference normal and along the lines of what I should expect when deciding which data type to use?

Comment: I guess this is because the Python type `float` is somewhere deeply implemented in C, while `decimal` looks like a module/package not built into the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Based on the time difference you are seeing, you are likely using Python 2.x. In Python 2.x, the `decimal` module is written in Python and is rather slow. Beginning with Python 3.2, the `decimal` module was rewritten in C and is much faster.

Using Python 2.7 on my system, the `decimal` module is ~180x slower. Using Python 3.5, the `decimal` module is in only ~2.5x slower.

If you care about `decimal` performance, Python 3 is much faster.

Answer (score 8):

You get better speed with `float` because Python `float` uses the hardware floating point register when available (and it *is* available on modern computers), whereas `Decimal` uses full scalar/software implementation.

However, you get better control with `Decimal`, when you have the classical floating point precision problems with the `float` types. See the classical StackOverflow Q&A [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for instance.

Comment: Yeah, I understand I'll be trading off precision for time, but is this big of a difference typical you think?